# How to shift text left in align environment

Tags: align

I want to align the following text left.

Latex command:

```
\begin{align*}
x1&=x~(\text{$1$ is multiplicative identity})\\
&=x+x~(\text{since}~\text{ a monosemiring with an identity is idempotent too})\\
&=x+x1\\&=x+x^21\\&=x(1+x)\\\text{i.e}., x1 &=x(1+x)\\
\text{or }1&=1+x~\text{by cancellation law}\\
\text{Hence, $R$ is additively absorbing}.
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Does `\text{\hspace{-5mm}Hence, $R$ is additively absorbing}.` work?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I want whole equation to be align left.

Comment: This is your 13th question, for future questions, please provide a so-called MWE as described here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228. Otherwise, it is guesswork what (relevant) packages or document class you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a proposal using `\intertext{}` instead of `\text{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % <-- also loads amsmath.

\begin{document}

\section*{Your Code}
\begin{align*}
x1&=x~(\text{$1$ is multiplicative identity})\\
&=x+x~(\text{since}~\text{ a monosemiring with an identity is idempotent too})\\
&=x+x1\\&=x+x^21\\&=x(1+x)\\\text{i.e}., x1 &=x(1+x)\\
\text{or }1&=1+x~\text{by cancellation law}\\
\text{Hence, $R$ is additively absorbing}.
\end{align*}

\section*{Proposal}
\begin{align*}
x1&=x~(\text{$1$ is multiplicative identity})\\
&=x+x~(\text{since}~\text{ a monosemiring with an identity is idempotent too})\\
&=x+x1\\&=x+x^21\\&=x(1+x)\\\text{i.e}., x1 &=x(1+x)\\
\text{or }1&=1+x~\text{by cancellation law}\\
\intertext{Hence, $R$ is additively absorbing}. % <-- intertext
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Update

This update is motivated by [Barbara](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579)'s (hurtful :)) comment:

> **This works only by accident.** The last line, when included in the
> alignment, forces the alignment point to the end of that sentence.
> Removing it from the alignment then allows the remaining lines to be
> centered as a group, and if the second line were not so long, the
> group would not move so far to the left. **In the present case, just
> moving the last line entirely out of the alignment/display would work
> as well.**

*(**Bold** formatting is done by Manuel)*

I also add (steal) the `shortintertext` approach that Bernard uses to have a more complete list of approaches.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % <-- also loads amsmath.

\begin{document}

\section*{Your Code}
\begin{align*}
x1&=x~(\text{$1$ is multiplicative identity})\\
&=x+x~(\text{since}~\text{ a monosemiring with an identity is idempotent too})\\
&=x+x1\\&=x+x^21\\&=x(1+x)\\\text{i.e}., x1 &=x(1+x)\\
\text{or }1&=1+x~\text{by cancellation law}\\
\text{Hence, $R$ is additively absorbing}.
\end{align*}

\section*{Proposal 1}
\begin{align*}
x1&=x~(\text{$1$ is multiplicative identity})\\
&=x+x~(\text{since}~\text{ a monosemiring with an identity is idempotent too})\\
&=x+x1\\&=x+x^21\\&=x(1+x)\\\text{i.e}., x1 &=x(1+x)\\
\text{or }1&=1+x~\text{by cancellation law}\\
\intertext{Hence, $R$ is additively absorbing}. % <-- intertext (amsmath package)
\end{align*}

\section*{Proposal 2 (Barbara Beeton)}
\begin{align*}
x1&=x~(\text{$1$ is multiplicative identity})\\
&=x+x~(\text{since}~\text{ a monosemiring with an identity is idempotent too})\\
&=x+x1\\&=x+x^21\\&=x(1+x)\\\text{i.e}., x1 &=x(1+x)\\
\text{or }1&=1+x~\text{by cancellation law}\\
\end{align*}
Hence, $R$ is additively absorbing

\section*{Proposal 3 (Bernard)}
\begin{align*}
x1&=x~(\text{$1$ is multiplicative identity})\\
&=x+x~(\text{since}~\text{ a monosemiring with an identity is idempotent too})\\
&=x+x1\\&=x+x^21\\&=x(1+x)\\\text{i.e}., x1 &=x(1+x)\\
\text{or }1&=1+x~\text{by cancellation law}\\
\shortintertext{Hence, $R$ is additively absorbing}. % <-- shortintertext (mathtools package)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is perfect answer. Thank you

Comment: This works only by accident.  The last line, when included in the alignment, forces the alignment point to the end of that sentence.  Removing it from the alignment then allows the remaining lines to be centered as a group, and if the second line were not so long, the group would not move so far to the left.  In the present case, just moving the last line entirely out of the alignment/display would work as well.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for the hint. Feel free to provide an alternative answer or to update mine. I am offline now and access the internet via a smartphone atm.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have updated the answer accordingly. Thanks again for taking an interest in my answer.

Comment: @gete Please have a look at the update. Barabara is a *true* expert on this matter!

Comment: Now that I look at the result, I think that using `\intertext` is probably better.  The gap between the aligned block and the comment is smaller, and I think (but haven't tested) that this should inhibit a page break should it fall at the bottom of the page.  (But this still *centers* the display rather than placing it at the left.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton :). Ok, so is my answer technical wrong? If yes, then please give me a hint to correct it.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: What you suggest answers the question as stated, so it is technically correct, and also generally good advice.  But, if the OP really always wants their displays shifted left in a *consistent* manner (which isn't clear from the question), this won't do it, so that might be added as a warning.  (I can't think of any situation where I would argue that `\intertext` is a bad idea.)

Answer (score 4):

I propose to use the `fleqn` environment from `nccmath` and for the last line, the `\shortintertext` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
x\,1&=x\quad(\text{$1$ is multiplicative identity})\\
&=x+x\quad(\text{since a monosemiring with an identity is idempotent too})\\
&=x+x1\\&=x+x^21 \\&=x(1+x)\\\text{i.e., } x\,1 &=x(1+x)\\
\text{or }1&=1+x\quad\text{by cancellation law}\\
\shortintertext{Hence, $R$ is additively absorbing}.
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I included your `shortintertext` approach in my updated answer and cited your answer. Hope that is ok. If not, let me know and I revert it.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: There's no problem. \shortintertext is not my private property :-)